# Why do some connections take very long, and others work quickly?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net, timeout

I have a web page that connects to a SQL Server 2008 instance, attempting to perform two stored procedures in sequence. The first one completes successfully, and then the values from the first are passed to the second. This query times out after about 110 seconds.

If I open a connection to the sql instance with SQLDbx, and perform the stored procedure, it completes, but takes 108 seconds (suspiciously close to the 110 for the ADO version).

However, if I open the connection with the SQL Server Management Console (2008), and execute the sproc, the query returns in about 4 seconds with 2 rows of data.

I suspect some kind of driver issue, but I'm not at all sure where to look. I'm hoping that some kind of configuration modification (on either the server, or the ADO client) might fix this, but so far my searches for answers via google have not turned up any useful hints.

So I turn to you.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the exact timeout message you're getting? SQL doesn't timeout because of long execution times, it's probably your web application that's timing out (PHP kills itself after 30 seconds by default for example) or a connection to server that's timing out. Are you sure it's performing the correct query/operations as well? SSMS will run any query faster than ADO's drivers, but not THAT much faster unless something is configured wrong or the driver is faulty.

Comment: true enough...perhaps I mistitled it, because of how we first considered the issue.  That said, I'm not so much interested in the timeout, as in the differences between the 108 seconds, and the 5

Comment: ADO is very slow, I would consider another driver if possible. It shouldn't be THAT slow, but I went from query times of 50ms on a normal query to query times of <1ms when using the default MSSQL driver for PHP instead of ADO. In my case upgrading my version of PHP also helped considerably. It's certainly the driver's fault in some way or another.

Comment: I should add that we've got this exact solution deployed against a number of sql server 2005 instances, and it behaves as desired there.  The issue is with the connection to 2008.  Plus, I'm fairly certain (*read hopful*) that the query analyzer SqlDbx isn't using ADO, but I could be wrong about the internal specifics of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO has problems with [stored procedures](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/6e5353b9-4837-4022-a535-5408ed6f852a/):

> Query Analyser works with ARITHABORT set to ON and ADO.Net runs with ARITHABORT set to OFF. This causes 2 query plans in the procedure cache. Depending on the parameters in the query these plans can be different, and therefore giving very different query performance.
>   ...
>   So when you get this problem its best to use the WITH RECOMPILE hint
>   to compile the execution plan every time you run the procedure.

Try something like:
`EXEC sp_MyTable1 'Parameter1', 'Parameter2' WITH RECOMPILE`
And see if the query runs any better in ADO.

Comment: indeed, it did help...  In SqlDbx, I get a return back in about 12 seconds.  This is much better indeed.

Comment: SQLDbx might be runing with ARITHABORT off as well, which would cause the same issue, so doing that in ADO will probably cut down your time.

Comment: I just toggled the ARITHABORT option OFF in the SSMS, and its now taking 110 seconds too...instead of the original 5.   THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is NOCOUNT off on both stored procedures?

Comment: I don't have access to the remote SQL server...at least not to see the sproc.